# Multiple grouped info in a single query

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a result set of scheduled transactions (Scheduled Date and Scheduled Amount), joined to a list of the actual transaction (Actual Date and Actual Amount) that was made.

I am suing SQL Azure.

What I need to get is, for each schedule_id, I need to know:

The Last date a payment was made (So, the MAX Actual Date) for a schedule.

The corresponding amount for that payment (So, the Actual Amount for the date found above)

The ID of the last payment payment (Actual_transaction_id).

The Next payment date for s schedule (So, the MIN scheduled_date where ACTUAL date IS NULL)

The amount of the next payment located above.

Here is the code to create the test data:

```
    SET DATEFORMAT DMY

DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    schedule_id INT NOT NULL,
    scheduled_date DATE NOT NULL,
    actual_date DATE NULL,
    scheduled_amount DECIMAL(16,2) NOT NULL,
    actual_amount DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
    actual_tranaction_id INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 77, '2014-06-17', '2014-06-17',292.18, 292.18 ,1 UNION
SELECT 77, '2014-07-17', '2014-07-17',292.18, 292.18 ,2 UNION
SELECT 77, '2014-08-17', '2014-08-17',292.18, 292.18 ,3 UNION
SELECT 77, '2014-09-17', '2014-09-17',292.18, 292.18 ,4 UNION
SELECT 77, '2014-10-17', '2014-10-17',292.18, 292.18 ,5 UNION
SELECT 77, '2014-11-17', '2014-11-17',292.18, 292.18 ,6 UNION
SELECT 77, '2015-02-17', '2015-02-18',504.00, 504.00 ,7 UNION
SELECT 77, '2015-03-17', NULL,504.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 77, '2015-04-17', NULL,504.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 77, '2015-05-17', NULL,504.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 77, '2015-06-17', NULL,504.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 77, '2015-07-17', NULL,504.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 77, '2015-08-17', NULL,504.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 77, '2015-09-17', NULL,504.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 77, '2015-10-17', NULL,504.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 77, '2015-11-17', NULL,504.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 77, '2015-12-17', NULL,504.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2014-06-17', '2014-06-17',700.00, 700.00,10 UNION
SELECT 92, '2014-07-17', '2014-07-17',550.00, 700.00, 11 UNION
SELECT 92, '2014-08-17', '2014-08-17',700.00, 700.00, 12 UNION
SELECT 92, '2014-09-17', '2014-09-17',700.00, 700.00, 13 UNION
SELECT 92, '2014-10-17', '2014-10-16',620.00, 580.00, 14 UNION
SELECT 92, '2014-11-17', '2014-11-14',600.00, 601.00, 15 UNION
SELECT 92, '2014-12-17', '2014-12-17',700.00, 702.00, 16 UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-01-17', '2015-01-17',850.00, 851.00, 17 UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-02-17', '2015-02-17',850.00, 853.00, 18 UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-03-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-04-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-05-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-06-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-07-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-08-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-09-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-10-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-11-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2015-12-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2016-01-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2016-02-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 92, '2016-03-17', NULL,850.00, NULL, NULL

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

And the expected result would be, in this case, two rows:

```
scheduleId, lastPaymentDate, lastPaymentAmount, nextPaymentDate, nextPaymentAmount 
77, 2015-02-18, 504.00, 2015-03-17, 504.00 
92, 2015-02-17, 853.00, 2015-03-17, 850.00
```

Is this at all possible, to somehow do this in an efficient single query? Or would it need to be broken up into multiple queries with there own WHERE and grouping?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
SELECT
  t.schedule_id,
  a.actual_date,
  a.actual_amount,
  s.scheduled_date,
  s.scheduled_amount
FROM (
    select 
      distinct schedule_id
    from 
      tbl
  ) t
  outer apply (
    select top 1
      actual_date,
      actual_amount
    from
      tbl a
    where
      a.schedule_id = t.schedule_id and
      a.actual_date is not null
    order by
      actual_date desc) a
  outer apply (
    select top 1
      scheduled_date,
      scheduled_amount
    from
      tbl s
    where
      s.schedule_id = t.schedule_id and
      s.scheduled_date > getdate()
    order by
      scheduled_date asc) s
```

The derived table fetches the id's and the 2 outer applys fetch the actual and scheduled amounts with top 1.

Comment: That nailed it! Thanks @JamesZ

Answer (score 1):

Try out this statement:

```
;WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY schedule_id ORDER BY actual_date DESC, scheduled_date DESC ) AS rn1 ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY schedule_id ORDER BY actual_date , scheduled_date ) AS rn2
               FROM     @tbl
             )
    SELECT  c1.schedule_id ,
            c2.actual_date ,
            c2.actual_amount ,
            c1.scheduled_date ,
            c1.scheduled_amount
    FROM    cte c1
            JOIN cte c2 ON c1.rn1 = c2.rn2
    WHERE   ( c1.rn1 = 1
              OR c1.rn2 = 1
            )
            AND c2.rn1 = 1
```

Output:

```
schedule_id   actual_date     actual_amount   scheduled_date    scheduled_amount
77            2015-02-18      504.00          2015-03-17        504.00
92            2015-02-17      853.00          2015-03-17        850.00
```